# microsoft sql server fake field

Tags: php, sql

Hello guys is there anyway
to make field at sql query to select it by php ?
for example

```
USE SRO_VT_ACCOUNT
IF EXISTS(SELECT UserID FROM [dbo].[_BlockedUser] WHERE UserID = 'ThElitEyeS1')
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[_BlockedUser] WHERE UserID = 'ThElitEyeS1';
        PRINT 'EXIST' AS status

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NOT EXIST' AS status
END
```

Then select it by php

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array(...)) {
   echo $row["status"];
}
```

Does it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 'EXIST' AS field_name
```

Comment: dude do you got email or skype or any thing i can contact you with it?